# Google Login Doesn't work through iOS Instagram App

Tags: oauth, instagram, google-signin

If I open a link on the instagram app, it opens a web view.

When I'm trying to log into my website via Google Login while on the Instagram's App web view, my google login would freeze at the logging in process.

Does anybody know how to support logging in via the instagram App for Google Login?

Comment: were you able to make it work?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code. Without knowing what language you are using its hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use ux_mode `redirect` option in google oauth config: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2clientconfig

Answer (score -2):

Google OAUTH does not allow for app web views and embedded app web view.

Comment: It works for https://www.imdb.com so there is certainly a way.